# User w/less than 50 rep being able to comment?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, comments

I saw the user [daR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2676855/dar) post a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371417/mail-function-was-not-working#comment34006799_22371417) when he had less than 10 rep. Was this a bug or was this posted as an answer and someone made it into a comment because it was helpful.

Comment: Guess: He tried to post that link as an answer and the system automatically converted it to a comment as "barely more than a link" - maybe it doesn't check comment privileges in that scenario?

Comment: [Their activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2676855/dar?tab=activity&sort=comments) definitely shows them commenting in a way that would be... odd to be converted from an answer. (@animuson) +1

Comment: Sorcery! Witchcraft!

Comment: @Emracool Well when the system converts it in that scenario, it never actually creates the answer. It's more like "well, this doesn't really *look* like an answer, so I'm going to post a comment for you instead."

Comment: An, yeah, on second glance, you're right, @animuson - it looks like all their comments were on their own posts, except for one, which might have been posted as an answer instead.